# Get all calls concerning patches in a Netlogo script

Tags: netlogo

I would like to parse all the calls to patch statements in a given nlogo script. For instance, for ants, I'd like to get:

```
Seq(
"sum [food] of patches with [pcolor = cyan]", 
"sum [food] of patches with [pcolor = sky]", 
"sum [food] of patches with [pcolor = blue]").
```

The idea is to make a wizard in OpenMOLE, which builds automatically an OpenMOLE script set with relevant inputs and outputs; so that it is ready to run through OpenMOLE,
Thanks

Comment: how are you defining "patch statements" here?

Comment: I mean all the parts of the code where calculations on patches are done, typically in the 3 strings I gave for the Ants example where a computation is done on [food].

Comment: You're going to need a more precise definition than that. What distinguishes those three strings from the rest of the code of the model? There are lots of places in the code where primitives having something to do with patches (and how are you defining that?) are used.

Comment: I try to find in a nlogo code all the possible inputs and outputs of the model. In OpenMOLE, we embed different kind of codes in a workflow. To parametrize them, we need to map their inputs and outputs with the dataflow. Concerning Netlogo, we can find good mappings for the inputs in parsing the input widgets. For the outputs, it's not so easy because they can be represented not only with globals but also with patches. So I try to find relevant "output widgets" where an output metrics is produced. In the ants example, patches are used to compute this metrics. So I try to find these metrics.

Comment: Surely relevant output metrics might not involve patches at all, but might be purely about turtles and/or links? e.g. for Wolf Sheep Predation you might be interested in `count wolves` and `count sheep`, or for Preferential Attachment you might want `count links`? I don't understand the focus on patches.

Comment: OK, it is not necessary patches, but actually something that the netlogo script monitors or plots, and which might corespond for us to a relevant output metric of the simulation. What I want to do is to propose some output metrics to the OpenMOLE user when he imports his netlogo script.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you actually want to pull code out of monitors and plots, as we discussed in the comments above.

The `.nlogo` format is documented, somewhat incompletely and poorly, at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Model-file-format.

There aren't already API calls for doing exactly what you want here, so you're going to have go delving into the NetLogo source code to figure out how to assemble what you need out of the pieces that are available. The best file to begin by looking at is:

- https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/5.x/src/main/org/nlogo/headless/HeadlessModelOpener.scala

It shows the needed calls for parsing a model file as a whole and splitting it into sections.

For parsing the interface section specifically, you'll see (in that same source file) that `WidgetParser.parseWidgets` does that, and there are cases for each widget type. So for plots and monitors the relevant code is:

- https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/acb5fb5f576fe235032f95617da0835126048ef5/src/main/org/nlogo/headless/HeadlessModelOpener.scala#L201-L207
- https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/acb5fb5f576fe235032f95617da0835126048ef5/src/main/org/nlogo/headless/HeadlessModelOpener.scala#L181-L186

as you can see, in both cases there are calls out to other code elsewhere that does the actual parsing.

Comment: I can get the pens instructions doing this ```workspace.plotManager.plots.map{_.pens.map{_.saveString}}```, which is what I wanted. An other question comes in an other thread.